# Obtaining a smooth result after modelling

Tags: modeling

Why is this difference is happening after I tried to Shade smooth this sword crossguard?  One side is smooth and the other on not.

As you can see I only applied a mirror modifier so far to model the other side of the crossguard.

[image]

[image]

This is a wireframe of the model.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have flipped normals on some of the faces.
Select all faces and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to make the normals consistent.

Also, make sure to check the mesh for disconnected geometry; select the object in Edit mode and click Mesh > Clean up > Merge by Distance. Find a value where the geometry of your model isn't affected negatively. If any vertices are removed you'll see this in the viewport toolbar.

Comment: Thanks, I used SHIFT-N instead of Control-N.  And all geometry fixed up.  Control-n only opened a new file. Just for others to know.